# Swift. Цвет курсора

Tags: swift, textview, swift4, cursor, uitextview

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно в `UITextView` поменять цвет курсора. Я прописал в `AppDelegate`

`UITextField.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
 UITextView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white`

Но курсор меняет свой цвет на белый только на второй раз. При первом нажатии появляется синий курсор.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Вы прописали этот код в didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? Если да, то странно, я сделал тест, курсор сразу стал белым.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk да, в didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Я сделал тест на iPhone XR и на симуляторе - курсор сразу белый.